# WordPress Custom Post Type Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

my situation is I registered a custom post type named `'products'` and I included `'has_archive' => true` in the parameter to enable an archive template for this custom post type, I also created a `archive-products.php` as the template for displaying post per taxonomy of `'products'`, but what I noticed is when I enabled `'has_archive' => true` what happens is `archive-products.php` acts as the index page template of the `'products'` custom post type instead of the `'page-products.php'` file that I created as the index page template for listing all the post of `'products'` custom post type.

then when I click a link to the `product-category` this `archive-products.php` uses the default `archive.php` as it's archive page template. it really acts weird and now I don't know what to do next.

what I want to happen is prevent this from happening and let `page-products.php` act as the default index page template for listing the posts (as it should be) and for `archive-products.php` to be used by `page-products.php` as it should be doing.

thanks I hope someone can help me into this issue.

**by the way I'm using WordPress 3.5.1**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in the last days, and take a couple of hours to search for a solution, in my case the solution was to add this following functions to you functions.php file: **flush_rewrite_rules(false);** 
I hope it can help you :)

Comment: thanks I'll try this one and come back here to inform you the result

Comment: Hello for an unknown reason it worked fine now, what I did is installed a fresh copy of WordPress, the theme now uses page-product.php as it's index for display items as it should be, my problem now is why page-products.php doesn't use archive-product.php it still uses archive.php even it has 'has_archive' = true, then I pasted flush_rewrite_rules(false); on my functions.php now it displays 404 page

Comment: Use flush_rewrite_rules(false); or flush_rewrite_rules(true); after the registeration of your custom post type for once and test.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this plugin for your custom post display
[wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-post-field](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-post-field)

on here create your custom post and use shortcode for display post.